# How is expando object internally implemented

Tags: .net

I am really curious to know how the Expando Object in .Net 4.0 has been internally implemented?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's implemented as a dictionary internally.

Check out Alexandra Rusina's blog on the topic [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/csharpfaq/archive/2009/10/01/dynamic-in-c-4-0-introducing-the-expandoobject.aspx), and mine [here](http://codinglight.blogspot.com/2009/05/introducing-systemdynamicexpandoobject.html).

Comment: @David: just wondering if you are you colour blind? The colours on your blog glare on an LCD monitor.

Comment: Sorry Mitch, no, I'm not color blind.   What do you mean they glare?

Comment: it implements IDictionary<> but it doesn't use a dictionary.  I left a link to the source code in my post.

Comment: Second link appears to have been hijacked, and keeps redirecting me to spam pages

Comment: Updated the link. (Also, check out Hans answer below. It's been 8 years since I wrote that blog and now I do JavaScript full tim, so I make no warranties at this point about the usefulness of my old blogs)

Answer (score 9):

You don't have to mess with Reflector, the source code for the DLR is readily available for [download here](http://dlr.codeplex.com/releases/view/34834).  Nicely commented too.  You'll find the source code for ExpandoObject in src\Runtime\Microsoft.Scripting.Core\Actions\ExpandoObject.cs

The data store for an ExpandoObject is an ExpandoData, available in the same source file.  The values are stored in a simple object[].  The ExpandoClass (same directory) keeps track of the keys in a simple string[].  ExpandoObject definitely doesn't use a Dictionary as earlier stated, but it does implement IDictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/), which now supports .Net 4.0.

Comment: Don't you mean which *now* supports .Net 4.0?

Answer (score -1):

The sure way to find out is use [Reflector v6](http://www.red-gate.com/Products/reflector/index.htm): [.NET Reflector demonstration video](http://www.red-gate.com/Products/reflector/video.htm)